# How do I display Nigerian Naira symbol in CultureInfo(c#)

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I want to display an amount with the Nigerian currency symbol (i.e N with double strike through "`₦`").

I've tried the ff piece of code which only displays the amount with just N and not with the properly symbol(N with double strike through `₦`)

```
@{ IFormatProvider currencyFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("HA-LATN-NG"); }

Amount: @string.Format(currencyFormat, "{0:c}", Model.Amount) <br />
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: font-family:courier new, courier, monospace;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the built-in nigerian cultures have a straight english `N` as their currency symbol. You can override that to use the [Naira sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a6/index.htm) instead:

```
var formatter = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("HA-LATN-NG");
formatter.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "₦";
```

After this all formatting with `formatter` will use the desired symbol, but be aware that the character also [needs to be supported](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a6/fontsupport.htm) by the font the website renders in. Some fonts may not include the symbol or they might include a different symbol in its place (I have seen this on my local machine).

Comment: reference link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx

Comment: Just specifying the culture info to `HA-LATN-NG` does the job perfectly for me  ```c# private static string GetFormattedCurrency(decimal value, int decimalPlaces, string culture)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
            return value.ToString($"C{decimalPlaces}", cultureInfo);
        } ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the symbol used in the CultureInfo is just an "N".  To view the proper version, you can use this shortcut.

```
char x = (char)8358;
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```